# How to use noConflict() when jQuery library is added dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have the following scenario:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="decorator.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

decorator.js adds a top menu to the page which depends on jQuery 1.4.4. The rest of my program uses jQuery 1.11.0.  decorator.js is implemented by someone else, so I have no control over this.  I've simplified the code in decorator.js to illustrate my problem below:

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('head').prepend('<script type="text/javascript"
      src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>');
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Question: How should I call "$.noConflict()" to reset jQuery object back to 1.11.0 after decorator.js adds the menu.  Since jQuery 1.4.4 is added in decorator.js after the DOM object has been created, the $jQuery object is always set to 1.4.4.

I've tried calling noConflict() after decorator.js in the header, but to no avail. My guess is because jQuery has not been added yet at that point.

Hoping someone can suggest a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the load callback of the script element like

```
(function ($) {
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
    script.onload = function () {
        console.log('onload of 1.4.4')
        console.log('jQuery', jQuery.fn.jquery);
        $jq144 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        console.log('jQuery', jQuery.fn.jquery);
        console.log('$jq144', $jq144.fn.jquery);
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script)
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TXLnk/)

Comment: Thanks Arun for the quick response.  Your solution works, and solves the problem I was having.